# Bypassing a license key for a program

Tags: software-security

I'm looking to potentially hire someone to bypass a program for me. It's a program for a game, the developer just up and disappeared about a month ago along with the website. It checks for a subscription key on the website. I would be the only person using said program as I wouldn't want it to end up being detected.

Thanks.

Comment: Which program? Do you hire someone for give him dollar?